# How to convert `pid` in json array into array of `children` form?

Tags: javascript

Raw array:

```js
const data1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    pid: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    pid: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    pid: 2
  }
]
```

How to convert `pid` in json array into array of `children` form?

How to turn him into:

```js
[
  {
    id: 1,
    pid: 0,
    children: [
      {
        id: 2,
        pid: 1,
        children: [
          {
            id: 3,
            pid: 2
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

### -----------------------------------

He recognizes `children` by `pid`

How to write a `function` to do it?

thanks

```js
const data = [
  {
    id: 1,
    pid: 0
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    pid: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    pid: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    pid: 2
  }
];

function toTree (data) {
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    delete item.children;
  });
  const map = {};
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    map[item.id] = item;
  });
  let val = [];
  data.forEach(function(item) {
    const parent = map[item.pid];
    if(parent) {
      (parent.children || (parent.children = [])).push(item);
    } else {
      val.push(item);
    }
  });
  return val;
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(toTree(data)));
```

Refer to `@chiliNUT`  answer, add a method :

```js
const data1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    pid: 0
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    pid: 2
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    pid: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    pid: 2
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    pid: 1
  }
];


function toTree (data){
  data.sort((a, b) => (a.pid - b.pid === 0) ? a.id - b.id : a.pid - b.pid);
  const map = {}
  data.forEach(item => (map[item.pid] || (map[item.pid] = []) ).push(item))
  const mapArr = Object.values(map)
   mapArr.reduce((a, b, index, arr) => {
    if ( a[0].id === b[0].pid) { // There are still bugs here
      a[0].children = b
    }
    return b;
  })
  return mapArr[0]
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(toTree(data1)));
```

Comment: There's more than one way to do this. What have you tried so far?

Comment: My level is relatively low, I have to write countless `for`s, I want to see everyone's methods, thank you

Comment: Likewise, I'd like to see your method first. Since you are using for-loops, as a hint you could implement it as a double for-loop. That way you only need two for loops.

Comment: .... too difficult.

Comment: You should still post it. For the sake of it was your efforts. And possibly you were on the right track. I for one will upvote it if it gets downvoted. Its a learning community right? I enjoy coding as you do. Just because it doesn't work (right now) doesn't mean its of no learning value. ... Sure there is likely a one-liner that could solve your problem. I personally don't know how to do it in one line. I would use a loop as you have done. I just need to see what you have done because thats the best approach to tackle open-ended questions.

Comment: By the way, you mentioned you were writing a bunch of for-loops. A double for-loop nests the 2nd loop in the 1st, so you minimize the hardcoded loops you would need down to two. Im not saying this is the best or even most efficient way. Show your code. We shall see where we can go next.

Comment: Okay I see your edits and current implementation. Its actually a bit more complex than what I was thinking. And possibly even using more advanced coding concepts than what I would solve it with. I will post an alternative solution in a moment, likely as psuedo code for brevity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data1.reduce((el1, el2)=>{el1.children = [el2]; return el2;});
const tree = [data1[0]];
```

You can use [`Array.reduce(el1, el2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) It iterates over the array like `map`, except: For the first iteration, `el1` and `el2` are the first and second elements of the array, then for the iterations after, `el1` is return value of the previous iteration, and `el2` is the next element of the array. Unlike map, which operates on each element of the array, reduce uses each element of the array to generate a single return value.

```
data1.reduce((el1, el2)=>{el1.children = [el2]; return el2;});
```

So that appends all elements of `data1` successively to the first element. Your final output should be an array, so

```
const tree = [data1[0]]
```

Follow up: if the data is not already sorted by id, you can [sort it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) like this

```
data1.sort((el1, el2) => {return el1.id > el2.id ? 1 : -1});
```

```js
const data1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    pid: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    pid: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    pid: 2
  }
]
data1.reduce((a,b)=>{a.children=[b];return b;});
const tree = [data1[0]];
console.log(tree);
```

Comment: @ebyteebyte Is your `data` always sorted as you've shown? This solution  *assumes* your `data` array is *already* in a flat tree format for a root node.

Comment: @ebyteebyte I'm not sure if I gave the greatest explanation for how this works, but I'm glad it solved your issue. You should read over the MDN docs on reduce, too, as it might help clarify anything I didn't explain well enough in my explanation.

Comment: @ebyteebyte GetSet makes a good point about the sorting of the ids, see the edit

Comment: @chiliNUT its an interesting solution. I however fear of other unsorted scenarios where `pid` is concerned.

Comment: @GetSet its hard to speculate further without knowing what kinds of real world data is being used beyond the sample data in the question, as well as what the sorting requirements are other than being sorted by id which was not explicitly stated in the question, but assumed.

Comment: Agreed on that @chiliNUT

Comment: This is interesting, but there is still a problem, if the ordering of id and pid is messy

Comment: @ebyteebyte Yes you will run into a need for a more robust solution since you are observing *now* the order of `data` is unknown as a requirement. You didnt say this before however. If I may ask, where is the data being sourced from? I dont mean a link but a general idea of the overall problem case.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to use recursive to loop on each element and put as child of the previous one.

```
const data1 = [
  {
    id: 1,
    pid: 0
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    pid: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    pid: 2
  }
];

function convert(arr){
    let counter = 0;
  let convertedArray = [];

  function recursiveFunction(currentObject = null){
            if(counter >= arr.length)   return convertedArray;

      if(currentObject == null){
      currentObject = {
        children: [arr[0]]
        }
        convertedArray.push(currentObject);
      } else {  
        currentObject.children = [ arr[counter] ];
      }


      counter++;

      return recursiveFunction(currentObject.children[0]);   
    }

  return recursiveFunction();

}


let newData = convert(data1);

console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Clever solution.